# understanding of getline() css method to extract sentence ending with full stop

Tags: c++

getline() gives text in each line that I got. But i did not understand how it works.

cam someone explain this?

```
// sentence ending with a newline
cin.getline(998,array1);

// sentence ending with a period
cin.getline(998,array1,'.');
```

How can I use it to get sentences from text which are seperated by `.`?

Comment: You can do it by calling `cin.getline(998,array1,'.')` in a loop.

Comment: There are two versions of getline, the std::getline version and std::istream::getline version. Documentation for both can be found here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/?kw=getline and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: thanks, can you please tell me what is `998` in above code? @Bansal, I saw those link. I think `istream& getline (istream& is, string& str, char delim);` can help me.

Comment: @Karimkhan Actually it's the other way around - `cin.getline(array1, 998, '.')`. 998 is the length of the array `array1`.